# Internet Explorer download history

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, download, history, internet-explorer-8

SANS's Windows Forensic Analysis poster saysI can find the IE 8 download history along the path:
**%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\IEDownloadHistory**
But folder IEDownloadHistory simply dosen't exist. Can anyone say where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows 10 location for the `IEDownloadHistory` folder is in:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\IEDownloadHistory
```

Perhaps there was a slight error in the article you found.

Comment: Yes, but I use Windows 7 (sorry, forgot to mention). Btw i cheked this folder too. Still nothing

Comment: I checked my Windows 7 machine and there is a folder for IE but no history in it. Microsoft has been replacing IE with Chromium Edge for Windows 7. That may have happened.

Comment: @user1292401: Is it that the above folder is present on your computer but is empty?

Comment: No, the folder itself is not on my win7 (but for example IECompatCache is exist)

Comment: Try `C:\Documents and Settings\Local Settings\History\History.IE5`. See the article [Easy IE History Audits](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2007/01/02/easy-ie-history-audits.aspx).

Comment: You may be out of luck. IE through ie 10 died some time back. IE 11 is now being replaced. Windows 7 is dead as well. So it may not be feasible to get the history you want.

Comment: @harrymc Thank you very much. But I need exctly IEDownloadHistory folder (assignment from a teacher from the university)

Comment: @John Yes, you may be right. But why this folder is present in your win7 machine?

Comment: It is just an old folder. Contents deleted, folder remains.

Comment: I fired up two Windows 7 VMs. The one with IE8 had no folder named `IEDownloadHistory`. The one with IE11 had this folder, but it was empty, so probably not used. My findings corroborate yours, so your teacher seems in error. I think you should look again at the article I linked (Easy IE History Audits).